# Changing rows per strip using tiffcp in entire folder

Tags: perl, libtiff

I'm trying to change rows per strip in all tiffs within a folder and its subfolders, doesn't matter if it replaces original or save as new file. Is there a way to batch change them instead of individual tiffs with:

`tiffcp -r 20 original.tif result.tif`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [`File::Find`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) :

```
use v5.22.0;  # signatures require perl >= 5.22
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);
use constant INPLACE => 1;  # overwrite source file or not?
use File::Find;
use File::Spec;
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);

{
    my $tempdir = tempdir( CLEANUP => 1 );
    my $dir = 'dir';
    find(sub {process_tiff($tempdir)}, $dir);
}

sub process_tiff($tempdir) {
    return if !-f;
    return if $_ !~ /\.tiff\z/;
    my $src = $_;
    my $dest = File::Spec->catfile( $tempdir, $src );
    my @cmd = ('tiffcp', '-r', '20', $src, $dest);
    die "tiffcp failed: $!" if !run_system( \@cmd );
    maybe_overwrite_source( $dest, $src );
}


sub maybe_overwrite_source( $src, $orig ) {
    die "Not a .tiff file" if $orig !~ /^(.*)\.tiff\z/;
    my $basename = $1;
    my $fn = $basename;
    if (!INPLACE) {
        $fn .= '_r20';
    }
    $fn .= '.tiff';
    die "destination $fn already exists" if !INPLACE && -e $fn;
    my @cmd = ('cp', $src, $fn);
    die "Could not copy modified tiff to new destination file: $!"
      if !run_system(\@cmd);
}

sub run_system($cmd) {
    my $res = system @$cmd;
    if ( $res == -1 ) {
        # A return value of -1 from system() indicates a failure to start the program
        # Note: The caller can inspect $ERRNO for more information
        return 0;
    }
    elsif ($res & 127) {
        printf "system(@$cmd) : killed by signal %d, %s coredump\n",
          ($res & 127),  ($res & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
        return 0;
    }
    elsif ($res != 0) {
        printf "system(@$cmd) exited with error code %d\n", $res >> 8;
        # Note: The caller can inspect $ERRNO for more information
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```